# Should I glue down sheet vinyl?

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring, vinyl

How does a person know if sheet vinyl is glue down or not my daughter  bought it at a surplus store to save money it fells cushioned and is1/8th to3/16th inch thick

Comment: It's really up to Steven as to whether or not Steven wants to put glue down.

Comment: Sheet vinyl is almost always glued down. It needs that to keep it in place on the subfloor.

Comment: @Steven Tyree could you edit this so that the title so that it reflects what the question is about to make it helpful for those reading through.

Answer (score 2):

Vinyl sheet flooring should be glued down in high traffic areas that will have rolling wheels such as wheelchair, office chairs or any heavy items on rollers as the vinyl can easily be stretched and easily torn if something catches on it. Speaking from experience:)
Worst culprit in kitchen is when you have to move a refrigerator, range, dishwasher and feet get caught when trying to slide back in. If your vinyl is not glued, find a thin sheet of plastic or something that has low friction and put that under the back feet when pushing the appliance back in. This should allow the feet to slip without rucking up the vinyl and possibly tearing it:)